# How to print JSON data with map in array React component

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have an array like this in React data file and I'm using the `.map()` method to load JSON data in component `ProjectItem.js`.

What is the most efficient way to print nested JSON object? I now want to print the title in projects array so I can debug it, show it on browser. I can't see `<div className="title"></div>` in inspector, what is the right function?

**Data.json**

```
{
"projects": [
    {
        "title": "Projecttitle1",
        "category": "frontend development",
        "description": "",
        "desktop": [],
        "mobile": []
    }
  ]
}
```

**ProjectItem.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './ProjectItem.scss';
import useWindowWidth from '../../Hooks/useWindowWidth.js';
import { projects } from '../../data'

import desktopImage from '../../Assets/Images/Projects/Desktop/123.jpg';
import mobileImage from '../../Assets/Images/Projects/Mobile/123_square.jpg'


const ProjectItem = ({ viewProject }) => {

const imageUrl = useWindowWidth() >= 650 ? desktopImage : mobileImage;

const { windowWidth } = useWindowWidth();
return(
    <div className="projectItem" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${ imageUrl })`}}>
        {windowWidth >= 650 &&( 
            <>
            <div className="title">
                {projects.map((data, key)=>{
                        console.log(key);
                    return(
                        <div key={key}>
                        {data.title}
                        </div>
                    );
                })} 
            </div>
            <div className="viewProject">{viewProject}</div>
            </>
        )}  
    </div>
    );
}; 

export default ProjectItem
```

**Console:**

empty

Comment: Are you getting data in `projects`? Can put log before map and check once?

Comment: Hi Darshna, I've tried `{console.log(json.projects.title)}` and `           {console.log(projects[0].title)}` to check once, no log data appears :(

Comment: I tried `{console.log("title" + projects[0].title)}` and log data Projecttitle1 appears on console, please if someone can put me on right track to print using map function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `import { projects } from '../../data'` is something like this:

```js
export const data = {
  projects: [
    {
      title: "Project title 1",
      category: "frontend development",
      description: "",
      desktop: [],
      mobile: []
    }
  ]
};
```

So when you map this object, you need to reference to the `projects` property like this `data.projects.map()`.

Example:

data.js

```js
export const data = {
  projects: [
    {
      title: "Project title 1",
      category: "frontend development",
      description: "",
      desktop: [],
      mobile: []
    },
    {
      title: "Project title 2",
      category: "frontend development",
      description: "",
      desktop: [],
      mobile: []
    }
  ]
};
```

App.js

```js
import React from "react";

import { data } from "./data";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.projects.map((project, key) => {
        return <p key={key}>{project.title}</p>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I created [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-carson-px0xc?file=/src/App.js) too.